# Flutter SmtpServer office365: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242))

Tags: flutter, email, office365, smtp-server

I get the bellow error if i use smtp.office365.com link to send mail with flutter SmtpServer function

```
HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242))
```

The code that i use is bellow

```
final smtpServer = SmtpServer('smtp.office365.com',
        port: 587,
        ssl: true,
        username: "toto@name.com",
        password: "akjsaeia",
      ignoreBadCertificate: false, 
      allowInsecure: false
    );

try {
      final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer); 
      return true;
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print('Message not sent.'); 
      return false;
    }
```

can anyone help me to resolve this problem?